# "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" for OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, opencv

I have installed OPENCV 3 using CMAKE on mac Yosemite. I am using Eclipse IDE and while building the solution its showing error:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "test1"  ./main.o   -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::_OutputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::get(int) const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test1] Error 1
```

I have added the header files and Libraries in the settings. Please help me get rid of this error.
Thanks in advance

Code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

   double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
   double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This was always a pain in the ass for me too and I'm not sure how I did solve it. Are you using the same compiler (clang, gcc) now (in Eclipse) that you used to build the libraries in cmake?

Comment: Yes, Fortunately i solved it by adding a few library files mention in a youtube video.

Comment: You need to link against `libopencv_videoio`

Comment: Please share your solutions here

Answer (score 0):

You can try compiling like this on macos:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/include/opencv4/ -L /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/lib-l opencv_core -l opencv_imgcodecs -l opencv_imgproc -l opencv_highgui -l opencv_videoio <filename>.cpp
```

You might need more or less in your compilation but the key is the libraries being linked as far as I can tell.

***Make Sure*** To check folders to see your version and whether they exist etc...